# Delete rows matching substring with LIKE?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, sql-delete, ora-04091

How do you delete rows from a table, where a column contains a substring, but the type of that column is 'Long'. (Yes, I know I shouldn't use Long, but I'm maintaining someone else's mess).

My first attempt was:

```
delete from longtable 
  where search_long(rowid) like '%hello%';
```

<sup>(Following on from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769787/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-the-long-datatype-within-an-oracle-database/771199#771199).)</sup>

This returns:

> SQL Error: ORA-04091: table blah.longtable is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just replicated your problem and got the same error - it seems the function can't work from within a DELETE statement.  The full text of the error is:

```
ORA-04091: table HOU.LONGTABLE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TONY.SEARCH_LONG", line 4
```

This procedural approach will work:

```
begin
  for r in (select id from longtable 
            where search_long(rowid) like '%hello%')
  loop
    delete longtable where id = r.id;
  end loop;
end;
```