# Problem with a ORACLE LONG datatype field when searching for it with JPA

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

**Solved with a workaround, read in bottom**

I have a model called "EmailTransmitido":

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(schema = "EMAIL", name = "EN_EMAIL_TRANSMITIDO")
public class EmailTransmitido extends EntidadeBase {
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "NRO_EMAIL")
    private EmailMensagem emailMensagem;
...
```

And another called "EmailMensagem":

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "EMAIL", name = "EN_MENSAGEM_EMAIL")
public class EmailMensagem extends EntidadeBase {

...
    @Column(name = "TXT_TITULO")
    private String txtTitulo;

    @Column(name = "TXT_MENSAGEM")
    private String txtMensagem;
...
```

Then i need to search through this field "

```
@Repository
public interface EmailTransmitidoRepository extends JpaRepository<EmailTransmitido, Long> {

...
        @Query("SELECT et FROM EmailTransmitido et WHERE et.recursoHumano = ?1 "
                + "AND et.emailMensagem.txtMensagem LIKE %?2%")
        Page<EmailTransmitido> getMensagensNotArquivadasByEnRh(
                @Param("enRh") EnRh enRh, @Param("pesquisa") String pesquisa, Pageable pageable);
...
```

But i receive a error:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            emailtrans0_.SEQ_EMAIL_TRANSMITIDO as SEQ_EMAIL_TRANSMIT1_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_CAMPOS_MSG as TXT_CAMPOS_MSG2_5_,
            emailtrans0_.DTA_AGENDA as DTA_AGENDA3_5_,
            emailtrans0_.DTA_ULT_ATUALIZ as DTA_ULT_ATUALIZ4_5_,
            emailtrans0_.DTA_ENVIO as DTA_ENVIO5_5_,
            emailtrans0_.NRO_EMAIL as NRO_EMAIL6_5_,
            emailtrans0_.STA_EMAIL_TESTE as STA_EMAIL_TESTE7_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_USERNAME_ULT_ATUALIZ as TXT_USERNAME_ULT_A8_5_,
            emailtrans0_.NRO_MODELO_DOC as NRO_MODELO_DOC9_5_,
            emailtrans0_.COD_RH as COD_RH17_5_,
            emailtrans0_.STA_EMAIL_TRANSMITIDO as STA_EMAIL_TRANSMI10_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_CAMPOS_MSG_BKP as TXT_CAMPOS_MSG_BK11_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_EMAIL as TXT_EMAIL12_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_EMAIL_COPIA as TXT_EMAIL_COPIA13_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_EMAIL_COPIA_OCULTA as TXT_EMAIL_COPIA_O14_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_ERRO_TRANSMISSAO as TXT_ERRO_TRANSMIS15_5_,
            emailtrans0_.TXT_REMETENTE as TXT_REMETENTE16_5_ 
        from
            EMAIL.EN_EMAIL_TRANSMITIDO emailtrans0_ cross 
        join
            EMAIL.EN_MENSAGEM_EMAIL emailmensa1_ 
        where
            emailtrans0_.NRO_EMAIL=emailmensa1_.NRO_EMAIL 
            and emailtrans0_.COD_RH=? 
            and (
                TO_CLOB(emailmensa1_.TXT_MENSAGEM) like ?
            ) 
        order by
            emailtrans0_.SEQ_EMAIL_TRANSMITIDO desc ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?
2019-06-03 16:49:12.542  WARN 10560 --- [nio-9500-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
2019-06-03 16:49:12.542 ERROR 10560 --- [nio-9500-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava CHAR obteve LONG

2019-06-03 16:49:12.549 ERROR 10560 --- [nio-9500-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/cm-api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava CHAR obteve LONG

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
```

This kind of error "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava CHAR obteve LONG" that means "expected CHAR got LONG" would be something related to the [LONG datatype in Oracle be deprecated](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430)? i mean, others field that uses differents datatypes works well with similar search queries.

I tried to make use of the @Formula instead of @Column, but it didn't work:

```
@Formula("TOCLOB(TXT_MENSAGEM)")
private String txtMensagem;
```

I tried to use JPQ Query method too but the problem persists, only with this specific LONG field. My main problem is that i can't change the datatype in the Oracle because it's a client's old database from where i only can read, and i don't have permission to make changes there, so is there some workaround to compare this field with JPA?

**I solved this problem with another table created to keep those data in CLOB format. As the column is of a fixed value and the consumer didn't object to it. Need to say here that i searched a lot and appears to don't have a good workaround for it yet, so if you face this problem too, think about doing the same or change definitively you column data type. Thanks all for the help.**

Comment: Yest, the LONG columns are deprecated. See this note in the [documentation](https://www.ing.jobs/Polska/Dolacz-do-nas.htm?keyword=Sta%C5%BC&facet_jobfield_name_level_1=IT%2BDIVISION) - `The LONG RAW datatype is provided for backward compatibility with existing applications. For new applications, use the BLOB and BFILE datatypes for large amounts of binary data.`. Just convert the column to BLOB - or maybe CLOB if you want to store text data in it (LONG and BLOB are intended for storing binary raw data, not text).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to search the Long datatype within an Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769787/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-the-long-datatype-within-an-oracle-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to map Long as LOB like:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "TXT_MENSAGEM")
private String txtMensagem;
```

Comment: Thanks for youy reply. I tried the @Lob, but the problem still. I can get the field, but i can't search for it using the LIKE operator, whenever i try i still receiving it: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG

Comment: Which hibernate dialect have you set?